# ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Shop\CartController::addToCart()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

So this function is supposed to add the product into a cart, but i've been getting the error

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Http\Controllers\Shop\CartController::addToCart(), 0 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\nerdS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php
> on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

I tried changing key words here and there on my controller, but nothing seems to do it. This is the the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Shop;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Use App\Models\Product;
Use App\Models\Order;

class CartController extends Controller {
    public function placeOrder() {
        if(session('id')){
            if(\Cart::count()){
            \App\Models\Order::store();
            return redirect('shop')->with('status', 'Thank you for buying!');
            }
                return redirect('cart');
            }
            session(['place-order-process' => true]);
            return redirect('login')->with('status', 'To complete your order, please log in. Not a member yet? <a href="'.url('signup') . '"> Join the club! </a>');
        }
    
    public function deleteCart() {
        \Cart::destroy();
        return redirect('shop')->with('status', 'The cart is now empty.');
    }
    
    public function deleteItem($rowId) {
        \Cart::remove($rowId);
        return redirect('cart')->with('status', 'The item was deleted.');
    }
    
    public function updateCart(Request $request){
        \Cart::update($request->rowId, $request->quantity);
        $data = [
            'cart_count' =>\Cart::count(),
            'cart_total' => \Cart::total(),
            'product_total' => \Cart::get($request->rowId)->total(),
        ];
        return json_encode($data);
    }
    
    public function displayCart() {
        \Cart::setGlobalTax(0);
        $data['items'] = \Cart::content();
        $data['total'] = \Cart::total();
        return view('cart.cart', $data);
    }
    
    public function addToCartByQty (Request $request){
        \App\Models\Product::addToCart($request->id, (int) $request->quantity);
        return \Cart::count();
    }
    
    public function addToCart ($id){
    \App\Models\Product::addToCart($id);
    return \Cart::count();
    }
}
```

My model for products:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class Product extends Model {
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }
    
    public static function deleteProduct($id){
        $product = self::findOrFail($id);
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($product->image);
        self::destroy($id);
        
    }
    
    public static function editProduct($request){
        $product = self::findOrFail($request->product);
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->slug = $request->slug;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->category_id = $request->category;
        if ($request->image){
            Storage::disk('public')->delete($product->image);
            $product->image = $request->image->store('images/products', 'public');
            
        }
        $product->save();
    }
    
    public static function getProductById($id){
        return self::finOrFail($id);
    }
    
    public static function store($request){
        $product = new self();
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->slug = $request->slug;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->category_id = $request->category;
        $product->image = $request->image->store('images/products', 'public');
        $product->save();
    }
    
    public static function getAll(){
        return self::orderBy('slug')->get();
    }
    
    public static function addToCart($id, $qty = 1){
        $product = self::findOrFail($id);
        
        \Cart::add([
            'id' => $product->id, 
            'name' => $product->name, 
            'qty' => $qty, 
            'price' => $product->price, 
            'weight' => 0
            ]);
    }
    public static function getProduct($cat, $pro){
        $product = self::where('slug', $pro)->firstOrFail();
        $product_cat = $product->category->slug;        
        //retun ($product_cat === $cat) ? $product_cat: false;
        abort_if($product_cat !== $cat, 404);
        return $product;
    }
    
    
    //use HasFactory;
}
```

The page view:

```
@extends('template')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1> {{$product->name}} </h1>
        <p>{{$product->descriprion}}</p>
        <p> Only for: &#8362; {{$product->price}}</p>
        <form id="add-to-cart" method="post" action="{{url('add-to-cart')}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="number">
                <span class="minus"> - </span>
                <input type="text" value="1" readonly/>
                <span class="plus"> + </span>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Add </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="{{asset('storage/' . $product->image)}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and my route:

```
Route::get('add-to-cart/{product_id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Shop\CartController@addToCart');
```

Comment: Please post the code of view from which form is submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `$product->id` in the form action's url(). That route parameter needs to be there so that it is received in the addToCart method in controller

```
@extends('template')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1> {{$product->name}} </h1>
        <p>{{$product->descriprion}}</p>
        <p> Only for: &#8362; {{$product->price}}</p>
        <form id="add-to-cart" method="post" action="{{url('add-to-cart/' . $product->id)}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="number">
                <span class="minus"> - </span>
                <input type="text" value="1" readonly/>
                <span class="plus"> + </span>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Add </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="{{asset('storage/' . $product->image)}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And you have declared your route as get instead of post. Following restful conventions your route should be declared as a post route

```php
Route::post('add-to-cart/{product_id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Shop\CartController@addToCart');
```

Answer (score 0):

Had u provide `product_id` in route (`add-to-cart/{product_id})`?

Comment: The route will not be invoked unless matched. So its safe to assume he did provided the id.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in your route (Route::get('add-to-cart/{product_id}) and the parameter passed in your function addToCart ($id)

Comment: Mismatch between the route parameter name and the parameter name in controller method will only affect implicit route model binding. Controller method will still receive the value passed as route parameter

Comment: @Donkarnash Implicit route model binding is done with type hinting the model + parameter name. parameter name - how they are defined in the route is crutial as far as dependancy injection goes, or laravel would be doing pretty dumb things which i think is highly unlikely.

Comment: @MohamedMufeed Yes of course for implicit route model binding to work type hinting model is required along with the method parameter name to match the route parameter name. However my point is that if the parameter name in the method doesn't match the route parameter name method still receives the value of route parameter from the url

Comment: I was saying it is highly unlikely that the method recieving the value. didn’t had any issues like this so I can’t be sure. But i had seen how the PHP DI works and it uses reflection to pass the parameter. So the parameter name must match the argument name there. Didn’t tested this in laravel though. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes pretty sure method parameter name can be anything it still receives the value

Comment: Oh then I shall delete mine too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a GET route vs POST, you have to change your form method from POST to GET and also pass the id in the action url -

```
<form id="add-to-cart" method="get" action="{{url('add-to-cart/' . $product->id)}}">
```

Answer (score -3):

Change your definition of addToCart method in CartController as following.

```
public function addToCart (Request $request, $id)
{
    \App\Models\Product::addToCart($id);
    return \Cart::count();
}
```